# Why is Java giving me errors that eclipse didn't?

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason with most of my .java files, eclipse gives me no errors and compiles them just fine. It even runs them exactly how i want. But when i try to compile them with javac or run the .class files that eclipse compiled, i get errors. Anyone know why?

Comment: Post your directory structure and the whole `javac` command you're using.

Comment: Because Eclipse doesn't use `javac`, so there could be subtle differences.  And may well be using different error/warning settings.

Comment: What **are** the errors

Comment: put your javac command and the dir structure in the question (as well as the errors you get. Just "I get errors" tells us nothing) they are essential. Without that information: you probably didn't add all the classpath instructions

Comment: And make sure that you're compiling to the same target version. The diamond in particular (`<>`) can trip you up if Eclipse is compiling to 1.7 and the command-line to 1.6.

Comment: It's almost certainly what @chrylis says: the version of `java.exe` you're using is older than the version  your Eclipse compiler is targeting.

Comment: Or, equally likely, that the classpath for your `javac` or `java` execution does not match the implied classpath in eclipse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eclipse has implemented its own compiler called as Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ).

It is different from the javac, the compiler that is shipped with Sun JDK. One notable difference is that the Eclipse compiler lets you run code that didn't actually properly compile. If the block of code with the error is never ran, your program will run fine. `Otherwise, it will throw an exception indicating that you tried to run code that doesn't compile.`

You could try NetBeans if you don't want to have those problems :)

Comment: Eclipse won't "run code that doesn't compile." It will, in some circumstances, replace code errors with code that's hard-coded to throw an exception if hit. This is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: Sorry, i didn't mean to say that's a bug. I mean that he could avoid that using NetBeans or always compiling en Eclipse :)

Comment: Thanks, but then is there a way to "bypass" those errors and let java run the code anyway as a .jar?